# How to select records which has difference between two dates more than 40 minutes? in Oracle Preferably

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have to select log records of current day where the difference between execution start date and end date are more than 40 minutes.

```
select * from iwdata.IW_MASTER_LOG
WHERE TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)  
AND (EXECUTION_START_DATE-EXECUTION_ENDED_DATE) >to_date('40','mi');
```

But this query gives me an error.

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
with a as ( select sysdate sd, sysdate+(1/24/60)*39 ed from dual)
-- in with sysdate and sysdate + 39 minute
select to_char(sd,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
       to_char(ed,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
       to_number(ed-sd) *24 * 60
  from a 
 where to_number(ed-sd) *24 * 60 < 40
```

in your case

```
with IW_MASTER_LOG as (select sysdate EXECUTION_START_DATE, sysdate+(1/24/60)*41 EXECUTION_ENDED_DATE from dual  )

select IW_MASTER_LOG.*
  from IW_MASTER_LOG
 WHERE TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)  
   AND to_number(EXECUTION_ENDED_DATE - EXECUTION_START_DATE) *24 * 60 > 40;
```

Comment: Hi Анатолий Предеин, Thanks for your reply. The query fetched me desired results. Can you elaborate more on how you handled the minutes.

Comment: is it like .. day has been converted to hours and then minutes?

Comment: when you date minus date this return is days number between those two dates, thats why, i multiply value on 24 to get hours, then on 60 to get minutes.

Comment: @Arjun Raja I've updated the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
EXECUTION_ENDED_DATE - EXECUTION_START_DATE > interval '40' minute
```

Furthermore, rewrite this condition

```
TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

into this one

```
EXECUTION_START_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) and EXECUTION_START_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1
```

because the former condition prevents Oracle from using an index on EXECUTION_START_DATE column and brings a full table scan

**----------------
EDIT
----------------**
`INTERVAL` clause works only for timestamps arithmetic.
If the query returns  `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`, then change the condition to:

```
EXECUTION_ENDED_DATE - EXECUTION_START_DATE > 40/1440
```

where a "magic" number 1440 is a number of minutes in a day (24 * 60).

---

> Can you elaborate more on why it prevents oracle from using an index.

See a simple example. First let create a test dable filled with random data:

```
CREATE TABLE IW_MASTER_LOG AS
SELECT sysdate - 500*dbms_random.value as EXECUTION_START_DATE,
       t.* 
FROM all_objects t;

SELECT count(*) FROM IW_MASTER_LOG;
  COUNT(*)
----------
     74130
```

next create an index on `EXECUTION_START_DATE` column:

```
CREATE INDEX my_execution_index ON IW_MASTER_LOG( EXECUTION_START_DATE );
```

Finally refresh table and index statistics:

```
exec DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats( user, 'IW_MASTER_LOG' );
```

And now check the execution plan of this query:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT * FROM IW_MASTER_LOG
WHERE EXECUTION_START_DATE >= trunc( sysdate ) - 1 
  AND EXECUTION_START_DATE < trunc( sysdate );

SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY );
Plan hash value: 3519959109

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                    |   149 | 18476 |   152   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                              |                    |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| IW_MASTER_LOG      |   149 | 18476 |   152   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | MY_EXECUTION_INDEX |   149 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)>TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-1)
   3 - access("EXECUTION_START_DATE">=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)-1 AND 
              "EXECUTION_START_DATE"<TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
```

The above query uses the index

---

And now generate a plan for a query that uses your condition:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT * FROM IW_MASTER_LOG
WHERE trunc(EXECUTION_START_DATE) = trunc( sysdate ) ;

SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY );
Plan hash value: 3290956462

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |   741 | 91884 |   378   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| IW_MASTER_LOG |   741 | 91884 |   378   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EXECUTION_START_DATE"))=TRUNC(SYSDAT
              E@!))
```

As yu see, the query does a full table scan - the `trunct` function prevented Oracle from using that index.

---

As @Анатолий Предеин sugested:

> you can create index on function for this column like create index
>   id_trunc_esd on IW_MASTER_LOG( TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE) )

He is absolutely right, let's examine his suggestion:

```
CREATE INDEX another_index ON IW_MASTER_LOG( TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE) );
exec DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats( user, 'IW_MASTER_LOG' );
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT * FROM IW_MASTER_LOG
WHERE trunc(EXECUTION_START_DATE) = trunc( sysdate ) ;

SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY );
Plan hash value: 1627571743

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |               |   148 | 19536 |   142   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| IW_MASTER_LOG |   148 | 19536 |   142   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | ANOTHER_INDEX |   148 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EXECUTION_START_DATE"))=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!))
```

Perfect - the query uses the new index. You can follow Анатолий Предеин's advice
But this index is limited - it can serve only queries with `trunc(EXECUTION_START_DATE) = ...` condition. It cannot be used to pick for example rows between some date and this date + 10 minutes - we still need an ordinary index on `EXECUTION_START_DATE` column. If I asked my DBA whether could I create two indices instead of only one, because I was too lazy and to rewrite one condition `trunc( date )` in the query, then he likely called me on the carpet.

Comment: Hi krokodilko, Can you elaborate more on why it prevents oracle from using an index.

Also when i tried that interval '40' minute. It gave an error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND"

Comment: krokodilko try to say, what if you use TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE) in your query iit's not use index on EXECUTION_START_DATE column, because it function, you can create index on function for this column like create index id_trunc_esd on IW_MASTER_LOG( TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE) )

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH IW_MASTER_LOG AS
  (SELECT SYSDATE AS EXECUTION_START_DATE,
    SYSDATE       AS EXECUTION_END_DATE
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE+1/24/60*30 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE+1/24/60*41 FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT *
FROM IW_MASTER_LOG
WHERE (EXECUTION_END_DATE-EXECUTION_START_DATE)>=1/24/60*40
AND TRUNC(EXECUTION_START_DATE)                 = TRUNC(SYSDATE); --started today
```

Oracle date is represented as fraction of days, what means.

```
1 - day
1/24 - hour
1/24/60 - minute
1/24/60*40 - 40 mins
```

TRUNC - when 2nd parameter omitted returns day.

Using **WITH** clause in my results in following dataset

```
07.15.2016 14:13:54 | 07.15.2016 14:13:54
07.15.2016 14:13:55 | 07.15.2016 14:43:55
07.15.2016 14:13:56 | 07.15.2016 14:54:56
```

Query returns only the last record (what is desired, because 41 minutes)

Comment: Hi peter, Thanks for the information. But, The query doesn't seem to fetch the expected results. I tried running that query and it returned only 2 records. But am sure there are lot of other records more than 40 minutes.

Comment: Hi Arjun,
I've updated my query - previously I forgot to filter only for today's records. Now the starting date must be today. If the process ran and ended next day, it doesn't matter. You will get the result as well. Unfortunatelly, I don't have a clue, why did you retrieve less rows than you think you should, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)